# Can ping but not access -Nextcloud

Tags: server, ping, nextcloud

I am running my own little instance of a nextcloud server on ubuntu 18.04.

Recently I rebooted the machine and since then it has some issues.

At first it could not resolve names so I added a DNS server address to `/etc/resolve.conf`, which fixed the problem.

Now the machine is connected to the internet, somewhat.

If I ping the address locally or go `ping www.mynextcloudserver.xyz` I get a positive response.

But I can neither `ssh user@localip` nor connect to the site `www.mynextcloudserver.xyz` via a browser.

The strangest thing: For a few seconds after every reboot I can `ssh` into the machine and then it drops the connection.

thanks.

Edit:
The fix:

`Apparmor` was failing to launch at boot, because the `snapd` package was not installed. I don't understand why that would break everything and why `Apparmor` fails just because `snapd` wasn't there. But it fixed the ssh problems.

The next problem was, that for some reason my firewall was set to only allow port 22. After `sudo ufw allow 80` and `sudo ufw allow 443` the server was accessible again.

Remaining Question: Why would `apparmor` fail just because `snapd` was not installed?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo ufw status`? It may be a firewall issue.

Comment: @vidarlo  thanks for the tip. For some reason my firewall was reset to block port `80` and `443`